# setting picture captured by built-in camera into an ImageView

Tags: android, camera, imageview

in my app i m calling built in camera for capturing picture but i want to set that picture into an image view following is the code . so what code should i add to it to set the picture into imageview.

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    Intent intent = new Intent("android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE");
    startActivityForResult(intent, 0);


}
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK && requestCode == 0) {
String result = data.toURI();
// ...
}
}
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Add a button and an ImageView to your main layout. When you click the button, first intent.putExtra to specify where the image will be stored, then start the camera intent. In your onActivityResult, if the resultCode comes back 0 that means the user accepted the picture. In this case, go grab the image from the path you specified as an extra of the intent. Create a bitmap from the file specified by the path, then set the image bitmap in your ImageView.